# Set CSS to Tree Header in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

Need to add color tpo tree header , I have tried several things and saw some documentations but need suitable and efficient way to apply css for Tree in  SWT.

Please suggest What will be the suitable approach ?

Comment: *I have tried several things and saw some documentations* - what exactly have you tried? Why didn't it work? Please, post your attempts.

Comment: Is this just a plain SWT app or is it in an Eclipse plug-in? Plain SWT doesn't support CSS.

Comment: @greg-449 I am using eclipse plug in

Comment: @BackSlash  I was going thro' official documentations of eclipse but I am notable to understand , do we have any sample code ?

Comment: So is this part of an RCP that you are writing or is the plug-in going to be installed in to Eclipse. You can only define your own CSS if you are doing your own RCP.

Comment: Do check the bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384906